# Creating an empty list in Racket

Tags: list, racket, null

I'm teaching myself LISP with online text of Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs, but it differs in small details with the Racket program I'm running to learn LISP on. For example, SICP says that the terminating element of any list is 'nil', but Racket doesn't support 'nil'. How do I create an empty list in Racket so I can test my own procedures?

Answer (score 15):

The empty list is denoted `'()`. So you can create a list like

```
(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '())))
```

This produces the list

```
'(1 2 3)
```

Answer (score 7):

Sean's answer is correct. However, if you want to be able to type `nil`, then that's easy too. Just run this once at the start of your session:

```
(define nil '())
```

Comment: Thanks. Of course, if I'd just thought about it, that solution is obvious. Thanks again, David

Comment: There's also 'null' and/or 'empty', depending on which racket language you're using.

Answer (score 6):

In Racket the empty list is designated as either:

`'()`

or as:

`null`

I would say that `null` is probably the more idiomatic of the two, and it dovetails consistently with the predicate `null?`, which tests for the empty list.

See the [docs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._null%29%29).

Comment: I vastly prefer to use `'()` over `null`. Two reasons: 1. `'()` is a datum literal, not an identifier like `null` is. That means you _know_ the contents of `'()`, unlike `null` which can be rebound: `(let ((null #f)) null)`. 2. `'()` works in all Scheme implementations. `null` only works in implementations (like Racket) which define it.

Comment: Also `(list)`is a possibility as well as  `'()` and `null`.